# Atom and R Markdown: Bookmarks and Line numbers

Tags: atom-editor

starting my R experience with Rstudio I switched to sublime when I started to work with R Markdown. My setup was working well until the sendRepl step broke all of the sudden and I could not get it to work, yet.

I switched to atom and was suprised how easy it was to get it running by using language-R bei LeeDom [language-R](https://atom.io/users/lee-dohm) and the fantastic R-exec by pimentel [R-exec](https://atom.io/users/pimentel).

Everything works fine, but I am missing setting bookmarks and the linenumbers in an Rmd.file in atom. Not sure, if I have overseen something.

Would be great, if someone would let me know, how to set bookmarks and toggle the linenumbers in atom in a Rmd.file. This all works in a R.file, but unfortunately not in a Rmd.

Thanks.